# Using waitpid or sigaction?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have understood that:
1) waitpid is used to wait for a child's death and then collect the SIGCHLD and the exit status of the child etc. 
2) When we have a signal handler for SIGCHLD, we do some more things related to cleanup of child or other stuff (upto the programmer) and then do a waitpid so that the child will not go zombie and then return.

Now, do we need to have both 1 and 2 in our programs when we do a fork/exec and the child returns ?
If we have both, the SIGCHLD is obtained first, so the signal handler is called first and thus its waitpid is called successfully and not the waitpid in the parent process code as follows:

```
my_signal_handler_for_sigchld
{
do something
tmp = waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
print tmp (which is the correct value of the child pid)
}

int main ()
{
  sigaction(SIGCHLD, my_signal_handler_for_sigchld)
  fork()
  if (child) //do something, return
  if parent // waitpid(child_pid, NULL,0); print value returned from this waitpid - it is -1
}
```

Appreciate if someone helps me understand this.

Answer (score 21):

You really don't need to handle `SIGCHLD` if your intent is to run a child process, do some stuff, then wait for it to finish. In that case, you just call `waitpid` when you're ready to synchronize. The only thing `SIGCHLD` is useful for is asynchronous notification of child termination, for example if you've got an interactive (or long-running daemon) application that's spawning various children and needs to know when they finish. However, `SIGCHLD` is really bad/ugly for this purpose too, since if you're using library code that creates child processes, you might catch the events for the library's children terminating and interfere with its handling of them. Signal handlers are inherently process-global and deal with global state, which is usually A Bad Thing(tm).

Here are two better approaches for when you have child processes that will be terminating asynchronously:

Approach 1 (`select`/`poll` event-based): Make sure you have a pipe to/from each child process you create. It can be either their stdin/stdout/stderr or just an extra dummy fd. When the child process terminates, its end of the pipe will be closed, and your main event loop will detect the activity on that file descriptor. From the fact that it closed, you recognize that the child process died, and call `waitpid` to reap the zombie.

Approach 2 (thread based): For each child process you create, also create a thread that will immediately call `waitpid` on the child process's pid. When `waitpid` returns successfully, use your favorite thread synchronization primitives to let the rest of the program know that the child terminated, or simply take care of everything you need to do in this waiter thread before it terminates.

Both of these approaches are modular and library-friendly (they avoid interfering with any other parts of your code or library code which might be making use of child processes).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But what I was actually looking for is: When I have both sig_handler and waitpid in the parent process, the sig_handler is called becaues of sigchld and then the 2nd waitpid as shown above in my Question returns -1. So can I just remove the 2nd waitpid which I am having ?

Comment: Yes, you can only successfully wait for a given child process once. It's actually a bug to wait again since the pid is "freed" by the first wait and might have been reused for a new child process (if you happen to have created another one).

Comment: @R.. Could we clarify the `When the child process terminates, its end of the pipe will be closed` a bit? To be really precise, wouldn't it be `When the child process closes its FD that is a connected to the pipe end, and there are no other processes having FDs connected to that pipe end, then the other end of the pipe will be signalled as closed (receives EOF)`? I believe that would explain more precisely what happens, and also the important special case of what happens if more than 2 processes having FDs to a pipe open.

Comment: Note that I tried approach 1, and suffered from a rare race condition when doing waitpid() with the WNOHANG option to make it non-blocking. The issue is the child process closed the pipe, but the child process had *barely* not exited yet, and so the waitpid() call wouldn't reap the child.

Comment: Because I am artificially limited by my uni in what C functions I am allowed to use, I ended up going with Qt's recommended method of having a single, global pipe that my SIGCHLD handler write()s a single byte to, and my poll() code then read()s a single byte from, mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43555661/13279557

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the waiting syscalls like [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) or friends -eg `wait4` etc- othewise you could have [zombie processes](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/79186.aspx).

You could handle `SIGCHLD` to be notified that some child ended (or stopped, etc...) but you'll need to wait for it later.

Signal handlers are restricted to call a small set of async-signal-safe-functions (see [signal(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) for more). Good advice is to just set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag inside, and test it at later and safer places.