# Correctly processing Ctrl-C when using poll()

Tags: c, linux

I am making a program, that runs like a server, so it is constantly running `poll`. I need to process both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. And while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> is pretty easy to work with when using `poll` (you just also `poll` for `POLLIN` on `stdin`), I cannot come up with a pretty solution for signals. Do I need to create a dummy file to which my signal handler will write something when it's time to exit, or would pipes fit this purpose nicely?

Comment: Pipe = dummy file?  Or are you talking about writing a file to disk?  The normal solution to catching signals from poll() is to write a single byte to a nonblocking pipe from the signal handler.

Comment: please tag the correct platform (Linux?)

Comment: @DietrichEpp I mean creating a `pipe` and writing to it if `SIGINT` comes.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487950/how-to-handle-signals-when-process-is-waiting-in-waitpid

Comment: Shouldn't the signal cause `poll` to exit with `EINTR` so you can just check a flag set by your signal handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) is what you are after - connect it to SIG_INT and you can poll for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> – see the example in the link provided (quite down the page – actually, they *are* catching ctrl+c there...).

Answer (score 5):

As commented by [Dietrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82294/dietrich-epp), a usual way of handling this is the "pipe to self" trick. First, at *initialization* time, you set up a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html): you'll call [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and you keep both read and write file descriptors of that pipe in some (e.g. global) data. Your signal handler would just [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) onto the write-end fd some bytes (perhaps a single 0 byte ...). And your event loop around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the older [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), etc...) would react by [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing bytes when the read-end file descriptor  has some data.

This pipe to self trick is common and portable to all POSIX systems, and recommended e.g. [by Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html).

The [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) system call is Linux specific (e.g. you don't have that on MacOSX). Some old Linux kernels might not have it.

Be aware that the set of functions usable inside a signal handler is limited to *async-signal-safe functions* - so you are allowed to use [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) but forbidden to use `fprintf` or `malloc` inside a signal handler. Read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)  and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: Feels like signalfd is a better solution, as it is a built-in solution for this very case.

Comment: Scratch that, signalfd is a Linux thing, apparently, so for macOS compat you would still need this.