# Can we dynamically create a process and maintain a process pool?

Tags: c++, c, process, fork

One of my servers, written in C, creates 'N' number of child process using `fork()` and delegates its task of running reports. It doesn't have capability of monitoring it's child process for alive or dead. The requirement as of now is to spawn a new process whenever the number of alive processes is < N. (Say for example, if out of five child processes, two died.) I should spawn another two processes. I am using `socketpair()` to communicate between Parent and Child process.

I read through various posts but it seems that they talk about the "pre-fork" mechanism.
Essentially, I am interested in dynamic creation of child processes using `fork()`. Is it possible? If yes, could you please give me some pointers?

Comment: What is the question here? If it's "how do I create a child process?" then the answer is `fork`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If what you need is to monitor the child processes and spawn them when they go down, then this approach may be helpful.*

Make the parent process to wait for changes in child using `waitpid` in a loop. Maintain a counter at parent to track number of processes alive. Based on your requirement, you can create one or more new child process using `fork` call and update the counter.

Man of [fork is here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork).

Similar question to track the [death of child is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377811/tracking-the-death-of-a-child-process).